# Find Time Difference between two dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to find the difference between two date&time inputs.

I have two cells for each input
e.g.

> Submitted:
>
> Date: 02/09/2019 Time: 10:00
>
> Completed:
>
> Date: 03/09/2019 Time: 10:15

I am converting these into text format and combining with the following:

```
=TEXT(D2,"dd/mm/yyyy")&" "&TEXT(E2,"hh:mm")
```

This outputs a string in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`
This output is done in cell **L2**

I then do the same for cells **F2 & G2** outputting to **M2**

I now need to try to find the difference between **L2 & M2**

Need some help with the formula on this one if possible.

Not sure how to handle the comparison of both time and date in one formula.
If there is a a way to avoid the initial conversion that would be fine too.

Comment: `=(F2+G2)-(D2+E2)`

Comment: That simple. Thanks Scott. Feel a bit stupid

Comment: With that you will get a number the whole number is the number of days and the decimal is part of one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same have been answered through comment by  @ Scott Craner and same accepted by @Batteredburrito

Answering behalf of @ Scott Craner , since the question is unanswered status.

Use : `=(F2+G2)-(D2+E2)`

With that you will get a number the whole number is the number of days and the decimal is part of one day.